# How to load an assembly in another appdomain in vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vsix

I've got this C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomainSetup domaininfo = new AppDomainSetup();
    domaininfo.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    Evidence adevidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;
    AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain", adevidence, domaininfo);

    Type type = typeof(Proxy);
    var value = (Proxy)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
        type.Assembly.FullName,
        type.FullName);

    var assembly = value.GetAssembly(args[0]);
    // AppDomain.Unload(domain);
}


public class Proxy : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public Assembly GetAssembly(string assemblyPath)
    {
        try
        {
            return Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
            // throw new InvalidOperationException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

For loading an assembly in a new appdomain. Now i tried to convert it to VB.NET but i get an error at the Directcast. (Cannot be casted)

```
Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim domaininfo As New AppDomainSetup()
    domaininfo.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory
    Dim adevidence As Evidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence
    Dim domain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain", adevidence, domaininfo)

    Dim type As Type = GetType(Proxy)
    Dim value = DirectCast(domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(type.Assembly.FullName, type.FullName), Proxy)

    Dim assembly = value.GetAssembly(args(0))
    AppDomain.Unload(domain);
End Sub

Public Class Proxy
    Inherits MarshalByRefObject
    Public Function GetAssembly(assemblyPath As String) As Assembly
        Try
            Return Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath)
        Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
                ' throw new InvalidOperationException(ex);
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? I'm new to VB.NET and don't know how to convert this code.

Comment: To get equivalent to a c# cast use : CType(object, type)

Comment: I just ran your code using Visual Studio 2017 and it worked perfectly.  Also, DirectCast should be just fine since there is an inheritance relationship between Object and Proxy.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but if i use this code, the vsix crashes. And i also use VS2017

Comment: I get a "File Not Found Exception" at `Dim assembly = value.GetAssembly(args(0))` this line. I want to load a DLL from a another project. Do i have to change the `domaininfo.ApplicationBase`?